# TV monitor detected, but stops working after logging in on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 and if I plug in a Sanyo TV through HDMI, it's immediately detected in the "Displays", but the screen stays black and says "No Signal".

The odd thing is that if I restart the computer with the HDMI cord already in, the TV works in the "Join Displays", at least until after the login screen. At the login screen, TV screen turns purple, and I can move the mouse around on the TV, as expected.

As soon as I login, the TV screen goes back to "No Signal".

Additional details:

```
$ sudo lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF119 [GeForce GT 610] (rev a1)
```

---

Has anyone else come across this, or does anyone have recommendations on how to start debugging? Happy to provide more details as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, just needed to install drivers.

```
$ sudo apt-install nvidia-driver-390
```